# Calculating Display Aspect Ratio for Anamorphic Video

Tags: android, google-tv

It appears that the Google TV/Android 3.2 API doesn't have the ability to correctly report the Display size for video content.

```
int surfaceViewHeight = surfaceView.getHeight();
int surfaceViewWidth = surfaceView.getWidth();

float videoWidth = mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
float videoHeight = mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();

float ratioWidth = surfaceViewWidth / videoWidth;
float ratioHeight = surfaceViewHeight / videoHeight;
float aspectRatio = videoWidth / videoHeight;
```

The probem appears to be the mediaPayer.getVideoWidth() and getVideoHeight calls.  As they are always returning the physical storage size of the video content, and not for those containers that support it the actual Display size.  I checked and there is no API available that gets the display size.   You can get close by using an external source like Plex Media Server which correctly returns the aspect ratio, but unless Display size is returned, the ratioWidth and ratioHeight calculations are always going to be wrong.

This really seems to affect the LG Google TVs as I'm getting most of the bug reports from those users of my app.  Is there a way to get the actual display size recorded in the container if it exists?

Update:  Here is a general primar on Anamorphic Content from Handbrake.

https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/AnamorphicGuide

Basically if only the Physical Size of the video is ever returned and used to calculate aspect ratios, then the video displayed will always either looked squished or stretched.  It may also always have black bars when it probably shouldn't.   The codecs are supposed to return a Display width and height to inform video players how the content should be displayed so it looks correct on the TV.

The MKV container format can report the correct information, in the EBML.  It looks though that the Android api is only reporting the pixel width and pixel height.  See the following java source (which could be a work around for MKVs).

http://matroska.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/matroska/trunk/JEBML/src/org/ebml/matroska/MatroskaFileTrack.java?revision=874&view=markup

Comment: I think you are going to have to provide some more detail in your question. The use of Display size and Container are ambiguous in your statements. Can you please scope the question in a way that can be addressed. Also it would help if you explained why your application even cares about aspect ratios.

Comment: Krispy: it is a video player app. Not all videos are encoded at a 1:1 pixel ratio. Sometimes videos have non-square pixels. Some GoogleTV devices have a bug that doesn't respect the DAR flag inside the video stream.

Comment: It'll help to understand why Display size is important. With anamorphic content the Physical Dimensions and the Display Dimensions are different.  If you solely rely on Physical Dimensions of how the media was stored the content will either look squished or stretched depending on the video information.  So in order to get Anamorphic encoded video to display correctly on the set and keep aspect ratios right, one needs the Display Dimensions so the correct aspect ratio for adjusting the SurfaceView can be calculated.

Comment: Krispy some additional information. An anamorphic dvd that has a 16:9 (1.78) aspect ratio will be stored physically on the disc at 720 x 480 however it should be displayed using 853 x 480 as the values.  720 x 480 is an aspect ratio of 1.5, 853 x 480 is 1.78. If you rely on the 720 number you get the content squished when calculating the surfaceview instead of stretched to fill the screen.  Currently only the Physical dimensions are being returned.

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot demonstrating the problem? I'll have a look tonight when I have a widescreen film and plex server to hand.

Comment: @Gaunt Face some screen shots here: https://github.com/kingargyle/plexapp-client/issues/12. JarreTV can probably provide more screenshots showing the issue as he participated on the bug as well and is affected by the issue.

Comment: Here is an example file https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B97a2IRj7gFpWGhuVFN6Rm9ZdjA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JarrettV One thing I noticed with that clip, is that the anamorphic mode is Strict.  Handbrake when I bring it up shows the DAR and PAR being the same.   Have you tried an encoding that has Loose instead of Strict anamorphic setting?

Comment: That setting shouldn't affect anything as it determines the calculation of the DAR up front prior to it being set on the video stream. I'm surprised it is even stored as metadata.

Comment: I am struggling to build this since the Android Maven project used simply isn't liking the SDK I have installed (either of them)

Comment: I'm hoping to open source a chunk of code which essentially forces the VideoView to respect a given width and height. Can i confirm if the height and width from the MediaPlayer is actually correct?

Comment: On LG TVs it is actual pixels rather than display pixels.